# Java: How to delete mail from remote smtp server?

Tags: java, apache, email, gmail

This sample code is from [Apache email API](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-email/userguide.html)

```
Email email = new SimpleEmail();
email.setHostName("smtp.googlemail.com");
email.setSmtpPort(465);
email.setAuthenticator(new DefaultAuthenticator("username", "password"));
email.setSSLOnConnect(true);
email.setFrom("user@gmail.com");
email.setSubject("TestMail");
email.setMsg("This is a test mail ... :-)");
email.addTo("foo@bar.com");
email.send();
```

If I use a gmail account in the authenticator this will save the mail on its remote smtp mail server. Is it possible to avoid or delete it after sending?

Comment: Did you take a look to this? (It's pop3 not 100% sure matches your reqs)

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/pop3/POP3Client.html#deleteMessage(int)

Comment: pop3 is for incoming mail, it's not for sent mails

Comment: You're right... I put the wrong ULR: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/index.html?org/apache/commons/net/SocketClient.html with Imap you should be able to access sent folder and delete it.

Comment: imap is fot incoming mail too :), I asked for smtp

Comment: I know, but seems the only delete available. Why don't send and then access to remote sent mailbox and delete the message?

Comment: this is what I asked, I don't know how to do that

Comment: I think it's possible because every mail client can delete a mail from both local storage and remote mailbox.